# How to order files by "full number name"?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to create a video from some png's, a thousand of them, actually. They are named numerically but with a step of 5000, i.e. `0.png`, `5000.png` , `10000.png` and so on.

Im trying to create the video using the command

```
ffmpeg -framerate 2 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" test.mp4
```

but the problem that I encounter is that instead of ordering them by its hole value, it makes the video using the first digit of the file name to order them. Hence the order I get in the animation is

```
0.png
1000000.png
100000.png
10000.png
1005000.png
1010000.png
... etc
```

which is not the order I want.

I've tried to rename them using info on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503530/how-do-i-add-zero-padding-to-filenames-that-already-have-numbers-in-them), but if I loop through the directory, I would do it in the same undesired order. And hence the renamed files would be wrongly enumerated.

How can I make bash to order them the proper way?

Comment: They keyword is “Natural Language Sorting”.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the ffmpeg command  and not near a computer but I believe you can produce a correctly ordered list with "ls *.png|sort -n" - so maybe a command like **ffmpeg -framerate 2 \`ls *.png|sort -n\`  test.mpg** will work

Answer (score 1):

You could do a few different things:

---

Rename your files with padded zeroes:

```
0000000.png
0010000.png
0100000.png
1000000.png
1005000.png
1010000.png
```

---

Use the version sorting option:

```bsh
file_args=()
while IFS= read -r file; do
    file_args+=( -i "$file" )
done < <(ls -v *.png)
# ..........^^
# or
#      <(ls *.png | sort -V)
```

then

```bsh
ffmpeg -framerate 2 "${file_args[@]}" test.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

1-liner:

```
cat $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.png' -print | sort -V) | ffmpeg -framerate 2 -i - -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Many players won't like 2 fps, so if it's not working add `-r 10` output option and it will duplicate frames to compensate (output will look the same, duration will be the same).